# How to change URL already rewritten with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify a RewriteRule for my routing. I'm using for test this page http://htaccess.mwl.be/ .

The request URL is :

```
http://myLocalhost.com/backFromPayment/1/?status=CLEARED&amount=1718.21&currency=USD&description=U900T2351&hash=e805f58f6f96d9ebd4e0ea9da69a37c10704d482&id_sale=8938744
```

.htaccess rules is:

```
RewriteRule !^index.php - [C]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$0
```

The output 1 URL is :

```
http://myLocalhost.com/index.php?backFromPayment/1/index.php?
```

This rule works for all pages but for the chunk "?status=CLEARED& ... " this rules is not sufficient.

So I commented below rules:

```
#RewriteRule !^index.php - [C]
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$0
```

and added this one:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} status=(\w+)&amount=(\w+\.{1}\w*)&currency=(\w+)&description=(\w+)&hash=(\w+)&id_sale=(\d+)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$0status/%1/amount/%2/currency/%3/description/%4/hash/%5/id_sale/%6
```

The Output 2 URL is :

```
http://myLocalhost.com/index.php?backFromPayment/1/status/CLEARED/amount/1718.21/currency/USD/description/U900T2351/hash/e805f58f6f96d9ebd4e0ea9da69a37c10704d482/id_sale/8938744
```

Another modification is as follows :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} status=(\w+)&amount=(\w+\.{1}\w*)&currency=(\w+)&description=(\w+)&hash=(\w+)&id_sale=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^backFromPayment/1/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/backFromPayment/1/status/%1/amount/%2/currency/%3/description/%4/hash/%5/id_sale/%6?
```

The output 3 URL is :

```
http://myLocalhost.com/backFromPayment/1/status/CLEARED/amount/1718.21/currency/USD/description/U900T2351/hash/e805f58f6f96d9ebd4e0ea9da69a37c10704d482/id_sale/8938744
```

My modifications doesn't work. But I noticed that when I modified the URL manually (copy/paste output 3) the URL works.

So I must modify this section of .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule !^index.php - [C]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$0
```

What to do to modify this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a query string in the substitution part of the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), this new query string overwrites any previous query string. If you want to keep the previous query string, add a [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag, e.g.

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [QSA]
```